# libvte-common package breaks package manager

Tags: 11.10, package-management

Updated to 11.10, but  I get a message

```
Error:BrokenCount>0

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libvte-common:
```

When I go to the software centre I can't add, remove or update, it tells me to  run the following command in a Terminal: `apt-get install -f`
which gets me nowhere as I don't know what to  do next.

Also message that the package catalog needs to be repaired but it fails when I press the repair bar.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 263371 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libvte9 1:0.27.90-0ubuntu1 (using .../libvte9_1%3a0.28.2-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libvte9 ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:0>: data error'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libvte9_1%3a0.28.2-0ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvte9_1%3a0.28.2-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
Error in function:
```

Any help please? (please spell it out as basically as possible!)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install -f` or not?

Comment: I tried but it asked me if I'm root (yes), all I got was a huge list of y

Comment: Yes! but got followingUnpacking replacement libvte9 ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:0>: data error'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libvte9_1%3a0.28.2-0ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvte9_1%3a0.28.2-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg retur

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!
put the 11.04 cd in and it pointed me to synaptic package manager - told me to open custom filters and go to Broken in the list. The  broken file came up, selected, removed and reinstalled.